# Smarty check if date is between

Tags: smarty

i need check if smarty now date is equal or between my two dates.
If dates is the same months its work. But if:
`Start = 19.01.2015` and

```
Stop = 1.02.2015 and
```

smarty now is `19.01.2015` it show no. Only if i change months it don't work

```
{if ($smarty.now|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y") >= ($value->getVariableValue('Start')) AND ($smarty.now|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y") <= ($value->getVariableValue('Stop'))}
yes
{else}
no
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

**try this i hope it will work :**

**Php file :**

```
<?php

$start_date = "19.01.2015";
$end_date = "1.02.2015";

  $smarty->assign('start', $start_date); 
$smarty->assign('stop', $end_date); 
 $smarty->display("date.tpl");

?>
```

**tpl file(date.tpl) :**

```
<{if (($smarty.now|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y") >= ($start)) AND (($smarty.now|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y") <= ($stop)) }>
yes
{else}
no
{/if}
```